# Underscore Map Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have been struggling with this problem the whole day.

I have got the following array:

```
controller.array = [{
  Equity: "0",
  Bond: "97.42",
  Cash: "67.98"
}, {
  Equity: "5.32",
  Bond: "13.12",
  Cash: "8"
}, {
  // ...
} /* ... */ ]
```

What I want to do is create a single array containing objects with combined values like so:

```
controller.newArray = [{
  Type: "Equity",
  Percentage: "5.32"
}, {
  Type: "Bond",
  Percentage: "110.54"
}, {
  Type: "Cash",
  Percentage: "75.98"
} /* ... */ ]
```

I have tried using `_.each` like this:

```
.map(function(item, value) {
    var array = [];
    _.each(item, function(value, item) {
      array.push({
        'Source': item,
        'Percentage': value
      })
    })
    return array;
  })
  .value()
```

What then happens is that it returns an array, containing multiple arrays with objects with my values.  Now my problem is that I cant seem to combine all the arrays that are being returned.

Any ideas? Please?

Comment: Could you provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use the runnable code snippet.

Comment: I believe his question is perfectly clear @ppasler - he's not asking for help with an issue but more on how to solve them. He wants to turn the first array (multiple objects with `Equity`, `Bond` and `Cash` properties) into the second array.

Comment: @JamesMonger it wasn't clear to me and I always like it if a running example is provided. No others have to make it a running example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transpose the array of objects into an array of values grouped by their common key.

Then you can map the values over to the resulting objects.

The `transpose()` and `sum()` functions are underscore mixins, so you can chain them!

```js
_.mixin({
  transpose : function(array) {
    return _.chain(array).map(_.keys).flatten().uniq().reduce(function(result, key) {
      result[key] = _.pluck(array, key);
      return result;
    }, {}).value();
  },
  sum : function(values) {
    return _.reduce(values, function(sum, value) {
      return sum + (_.isNumber(value) ? value : parseFloat(value));
    }, 0);
  }
});

var array = [{
  Equity: "0",
  Bond: "97.42",
  Cash: "67.98"
}, {
  Equity: "5.32",
  Bond: "13.12",
  Cash: "8"
}];

var result = _.chain(array).transpose().map(function(value, key) {
  return {
    Type: key,
    Percentage: _.sum(value).toFixed(2)
  };
}).value();

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way, using only JavaScript could be to use `map` and `reduce` functions:

```js
var data = [{Equity: "0", Bond: "97.42", Cash: "67.98"},
            {Equity: "5.32", Bond: "13.12", Cash: "8"}];

var sumMap = data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(itemKey) {
    if (acc[itemKey] === undefined) {
      acc[itemKey] = 0;
    }
    acc[itemKey] += parseFloat(item[itemKey]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
var result = Object.keys(sumMap).map(function(itemKey) {
  return {
    "Type": itemKey,
    "Percentage": "" + sumMap[itemKey]
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

The intermediate result `sumMap` will be something like this:

```
 {
   Equity: 5.32,
   Bond: 110.54,
   Cash: 75.98
 }
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jL4y36cd/) (thanks to CPHPython).

Comment: Nice vanilla solution, but you may want to use parseFloat instead, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jL4y36cd/) (open the console first to test). Correct the answer, add a running snippet and I'll upvote.

Comment: thank you! :) haha, I don't know why did I use `parseInt`, nice catch! :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to sum each type then this should do:

```
keys = {Equity: 0, Bond: 0, Cash: 0}
//newArray is the array from your question
newArray.forEach(function(obj) { 
   keys[obj.Type] +=  obj.Percentage})
```